# Do android apps look at your pictures if not needed?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Maybe I'm a bit paranoia, but I'm wondering if apps who don't work with your documents or files (games for examples) look at your pictures/files for advertising purposes. They will exist, but I'm I correct that this is a minority of the apps?

Comment: That is the reason since Android 11 the permission model to access the files on the "sdcard" section is split into multiple run-time permissions instead of one permission for "everything or nothing".

Comment: But do you think that this is a common practice or rather rare?

Answer (score 1):

Android apps can only access some resources if you explicitly give permissions for that. One app can request this permission, but you are free to give it or not, and even to revoke that permission in a later moment. These are the permission types you can give:

- Body sensors: Get sensor info about your vital signs.
- Calendar: Use your default calendar.
- Call logs: Access and change your call history.
- Camera: Use your camera to take pictures or videos.
- Contacts: Access your contacts list.
- Location: Gets your device’s
  location. Learn about location settings.
- Microphone: Record audio.
- Nearby Bluetooth devices: Apps can discover and connect to nearby
  devices.
- Phone: Make and manage phone calls.
- Physical activity: Get info about your activity like walking, biking,
  step count, and more.
- SMS: Access incoming and send outgoing text
  messages.
- Storage: Get photos and other files on your phone.
- Files
  and media: Use photos, media, and other files on your phone.

If you want, for instance, to revoke the microphone or camera access from all apps in your device, follow these steps:

1. On your phone, open the Settings app.
2. Tap Privacy.
3. Turn off Camera access or Microphone access.

The same thing can be done for your storage, for instance...

[More information](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9431959?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctypes-of-permissions%2Cdisable-camera-or-microphone-access-on-your-device)